# Can you set a time limit with the Twilio Voicemail Twimlet?

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

I'm using the Voicemail Twimlet and I'm receiving these automated calls that play recordings related to politics for 30 minutes or longer. The Twimlet doesn't have a time limit option that I can find, so it just records these giant mp3 files. I want to just hangup the call after 3 minutes or so. Does anyone know a way to set a time limit for a twimlet or how to create quick Twilio php script that could handle this?
https://www.twilio.com/labs/twimlets/voicemail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ricky from Twilio here.

Although you can't set a timeout using the twimlet, you can do this using [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml). The  [verb](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record) has an attribute called maxLength that will accomplish what you're looking for. As an example, if you returned this TwiML your recording would timeout after 30 seconds:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Record maxLength="30" />
</Response>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I used the following code:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Play>voicemail.mp3</Play>
    <Record maxLength="120" action="mail.php" />
</Response>`

To send the email I used this info: https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/voice/how-can-i-forward-recordings-to-my-email-inbox

I still don't know how to include the transcription in the email.